# Arkanoid Physics (projectile physics simulation)

Tags: math, physics, game-physics

I have a slider, whose velocity I calculate via the difference between positions each tick (this can sometimes be huge due to using it via a touch screen, so maybe I should clamp this at some arbitrary number to avoid some of these issues?)

I have a ball with a 3 dimensional direction vector and a velocity.

When the ball collides with the slider I invert its direction on the Z axis (going away from the slider) and then use the sliders velocity to manipulate its X (left <-> right) direction. so:

`ball.direction.x += (slider_friction * slider_velocity)`

Now the ball update is carried out as follows:

```
velocity = ball.velocity * time
ball.direction.normalise()
ball.position = ball.direction * ball.velocity
```

This seems to work great, except in some cases it seems to be very possible for any of the balls axis to equal zero, resulting in it never returning to the slider in some cases. What would be a good solution to this? And what would be a good way to handle the response with the blocks when it collides with them? Should it return to bouncing at right angles, or should it maintain reflecting with the same bounce modifiers applied by the slider? Also any other physics tips for this kind of projectile simulation would be appreciated.

Comment: Im guessing that the normalise of the direction will be where the granularity of the axis gets lost, i.e if Z was 0.1 and X was 15 the normalise would make it 1 and 0 (ish). and without the normalise it would allow the projectile to reach obscene speeds, so what would be a better way of doing this?

Comment: When the ball comes down (e.g 0,-1) and hits a very fast slider (e.g. +100), what do you *want* it to do?

Comment: Well I guess I would like to restrict the angle in which it can move, i.e never parallel to the slider, but its more a question of the best way to achieve this, is normalising then clamping the angle the best way? or is not normalising and clamping the velocity provided from the slider better?

Comment: Completely at a tangent (haha), but `velocity = ball.velocity * time` and `ball.position = ball.direction * ball.velocity` suggest you could do with some improved variable names...

Comment: lol. I did write them as pseudo code but someone changed the tags to be actual code. but what is wrong with those as names? position is a position vector. direction being a direction vector and velocity being a scaler velocity value I guess the resultant velocity should be something relating to change in position if that's what you are referring to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmm, this is a nice problem; the thing is, a good solution (that is, one that looks and feels just like real physics) is by nature one that uses real physics. Luckily, most of the newtonian physics within this problem can be easily simplified. Pardon me if I get overly verbose, but physics tends to do that to you.

[image]

So, to define the problem, this is an elastic (as in, no energy is absorbed) collision between an arkanoid ball and a paddle. First of all, since you've obviously got the vertical motion down, I won't concern myself with that. So what follows is all on the horizontal components of the collsions.

The paddle transfers a certain amount of  *horizontal* momentum to the ball (although, since this is Arkanoid physics, the paddle loses no momentum itself :P). This can be recieved in two ways -- by making the ball spin, and by giving the ball some horizontal momentum (obviously, if the ball already has horizontal momentum or spin, the added momentum will be...well, added).

delta momentum + delta angular momentum = momentum paddle gave

Of course, it might be annoying to work with momenta, since you don't *really* have to. I would asssume that the ball and the paddle have constant mass (that is, the ball does not suddenly become heavier, although you could easily work with that), because then you could factor the mass of each out of your momentum equations. So then,

delta horizontal velocity + delta angular velocity = paddle velocity * mass of paddle / mass of ball

To get an equation you could use out of this, you have to set how much of the momentum from the paddle would go into the spin, and how much would go into ball movement. For example,

```
mass_factor = 2 # ratio between paddle and ball masses
angular_factor = 0.3 # the amount of the paddle's movement which will go into the ball's spin

# and now for the bouncy-bouncy

ball.hVel += (1 - angular_factor) * paddle.hVel * mass_factor * friction or whatever
ball.spin += angular_factor * paddle.hVel * mass_factor * friction or whatever
ball.vVel = - ball.vVel # of course, its vertical velocity reverses
```

This will be enough to set up a quasi-realistic bounce, but one nugget remains (which you don't need to adress, but adressing it would make your Arkanoid amazing) -- what happens to all that spin? Can the spin be used somehow for more interesting bounces?

So, to recap, your spin is the speed at which the periphery of the ball is moving relative to the center. Thing is, whenever a spinning ball bounces against something stationary, its spin changes as well as its velocity. If a spinning ball hits a stationary surface, the bal gets a little "kick" in the direction *opposite* that of its spin (if spin is measured at the point of contact), and the spin will change.

```
#Upon collision with a surface (assumed horizontal, with the ball above the surface)
ball.hVel += -(ball.Avel * rate) # Where "rate" is the ratio which determines how much angular velocity decays with each bounce
ball.Avel *= 1 - rate # So the angular velocity decays properly
```

Since angular velocity is rotationally symmetric, you would just treat collisions at different angles (balls on walls, balls on ceilings) as rotations of this.

Phew, that was unintentionally long-winded, and it is nowhere near complete, but it's enough to answer your question IMHO.

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer! hopefully ill get some free time to have a go at implementing these principles in the next couple of weeks, am I ok to comment here with any questions? thanks.